# "I like it that" vs. "I like that"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, pronouns, clauses, dummy-it

I want to express the following: You are blaming me for your lack of concern and I like that (in a sarcastic way).

Which one of the following sentences would be correct?

> - I like it that your lack of concern is my fault.
> - I like that your lack of concern is my fault.

Comment: The sarcastic idiom is confined to 'I like that!' Thus: "Your lack of concern is my fault?! I like that!"

Comment: The grammatical question is whether the superfluous dummy _it_ is required, or whether _like_ can just take a tensed complement without extraposition. Either one's OK with me, but opinions vary on the second one.

Comment: But the answer to OP's question is 'Neither' - they may be grammatically correct, but would rarely if ever be used to convey the sarcastic sense.

Comment: When I'm reading the sentences, the manner of saying those sentences tells me if it's sarcastic or not. :P

Comment: Hesitatingly, may I suggest the following: "So your lack of concern is my fault, is it? That's *very* good/clever/intelligent." I agree with @EdwinAshworth that "I like that" sounds better at the end, and the "art" of sarcasm usually involves heavily stressing the key word and leaving the cutting comment at the end.

Comment: In the sarcastic usage, I would say, “I like how your lack of concern is somehow _my_ fault”.

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct, and both convey the same information.  The only difference is in the syntax: the grammatical way in which you are conveying your point.  Let us look at the first example:

> I like it that your lack of concern is my fault.

The word *that* has many uses in English.  In this example, *that* is the relative pronoun, and refers back to *it* so as to give more information.

What do you like?  You like *it.*  However, the listener knows nothing about what *it* is, and so you add a relative clause, beginning with *that,* which gives more information about *it.*  Similar constructions include the following:

> This is the house *that* I want.
>
> Here is the man *that* I was talking about.
>
> The only good thing *that* happened last night was...

As for your second example:

> I like that your lack of concern is my fault.

*That* is a type of subordinating conjunction, called a complimentizer.  Unsurprisingly, it takes the second clause and makes it the complement of the first clause.  Because of the complimentizer *that,* the whole phrase *your lack of concern is my fault* becomes the object of the verb *like.*  Similar constructions are as follow:

> I said *that* I wanted to.
>
> He hopes *that* his brother will come home to see him.
>
> The king commands *that* his fool attend the court.

As you can see, both constructions occur frequently in English and neither is inherently better than the other.  If I am to make a recommendation, however, the *it* in the first example feels superfluous; it doesn't contain anything necessary in and of itself.  As always with style, the choice is ultimately yours.

Answer (score 2):

> I like it that your lack of concern is my fault.

This one is correct. Generally, you do not say "I like that-clause".

http://framenet2.icsi.berkeley.edu/frameSQL/book/5_Assigning_Grammatical_Functions.html
I quote a part related below.

For example, the verb like can occur in sentences with extraposed objects:

(3) I like it [that you speak French].

FrameNet annotations of example sentences demonstrate that the verb like may take a null object it followed by a complement clause as one of its valence options. It is possible to retrieve examples of extraposed objects for like and other predicates from the database by searching for combinations of null object and complement clause.

Comment: Wouldn't "that you speak French" be a noun clause, and so the sentence would be "I like [noun]," which is certainly correct?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Theoretically, you are right. "I like that-clause" might be acceptable but informal.

Comment: @WChargin What makes you think *that you speak French* is a noun clause? It doesn't pattern with noun clauses generally. I think that the correct answer here is that *like* is undergoing a meaning-shift in English, and many speakers (including myself) find it fully acceptable, if informal, with a *that*-clause complement.

Comment: These sites ([DeAnza college](http://faculty.deanza.edu/flemingjohn/stories/storyReader$23), [University of Pittsburgh](http://www2.pitt.edu/~atteberr/comp/0150/grammar/nounclauses.html), [Portland Community College](http://spot.pcc.edu/map/prev/nounclause-that.htm)) are the top three Google results for `noun clause with that  site:edu` and all demonstrate the same structure. [Wikipedia agrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_clause#Noun_clause), as does [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/noun+clause). It's simply the definition. What do you think a noun clause is?

Answer (score 2):

In spoken English, there really is no difference between the two. They are equally acceptable. I rarely hear the "I like it that" form, as people tend to eliminate any unnecessary sounds and words when speaking.

If you're being sarcastic (which you certainly are with a sentence constructed the way yours is), then I would omit "it". In fact, I can't think of a good reason ever to include it. It sounds a little stuffy.