# Pragmatic difference between two structures like that vs like it that

Tags: pragmatics

Is there any pargamtic difference between the following sentences?

1. The children **like that** the clown performs in a circus.
2. The children **like it that** the clown performs in a circus.

Comment: The first is said and the second is standard grammar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I like it that" vs. "I like that"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134005/i-like-it-that-vs-i-like-that) (Read Professor Lawler's comment.)